# Is it possible to use predefined ivysettings.xml from a grails app

Tags: grails, ivy

Today we use ivy for our existing Java projects.  We are looking at adding a grails application.  I have found how to set up the BuildConfig.groovy to use our repos. However we have all of this information defined in a shared ivysettings.xml file for all of our Java apps, is it possible to tell Grails to use the default resolver from that ivysettings file?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in BuildConfig.groovy (example found from [Users mailing list](http://n4.nabble.com/Use-custom-ivysettings-xml-in-1-2-tp1561258p1561258.html))

```
repositories {
    resolver sandboxResolver()
}

private DependencyResolver sandboxResolver() {  
    def ivySettings = new IvySettings()
    ivySettings.load(new File("C:\myivysettingsfile.xml")) //You also can pass a  URL object here
    def ivyResolver = ivySettings.getDefaultResolver()
    return ivyResolver
}
```